# How do you fix "403 Forbidden Error" that results from placing local images on a website?

Tags: http, http-status-code-403

I am locally hosting a website on my mac (all files are located in the 
"Sites" folder on my computer (~/Sites).  I am attempting to add an image to my website and I am getting a 403 Forbidden Error: :"NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - http://172.28.15.5/~user/image.png"

Does anyone know

Comment: Are you running Apache on your MAC? You may need to edit httpd.conf and change `Deny From All` applied to your root directory to `Allow From All` so that external IPs can access the server.

Comment: Have you checked the permissions on the directory and on the file itself?  Is it readable by everyone?

Answer (score 5):

Check permissions on the file and the Sites folder. Make sure the Sites folder has o+x (public enter) permission and image has o+r (public read) permission, since when you try to access it using web browser you are considered public